# Mention of Siva cursing Saudasa(Somadatta) in Skanda Purana

Tags: skanda-purana, reference-request

Does Skanda purana mention the incident of Shiva cursing Saudasa to live as a Rakshasa?

Comment: Who is Saudas or Somadatta? Why was he cursed? Where did you learn about this incident? [edit] to make your question more clear. Not everyone knows about Saudasa or Somadatta. There is a possibility that there are multiple persons in the Puranas with the same name.